# Android preview layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a problem with the preview design on the Android Studio platform.

I will attach two photos: 

Designer: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X81cZ.png)

My phone: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYBg3.png)

The problem is that the preview on the Android Studio doesn't show the exact same thing as my phone.You can definitely see that the description field is not being shown on my phone.
The XML code-snippet is below:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/yoyaku_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/yoyakulogo2" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/yoyaku_image"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:text="Phone number:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/actual_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:text="076767674764764" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:text="Location:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location_view_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:text="74 rue des cascades 75020 Paris " />
    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    <android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linear_layout_2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:text="Description:" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description_view_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:text=" record storespecialized in Electronic Music based in Paris" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem can be solved using a ScrollView,but initially i did not want to use it.
What caused this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that preview is just an estimate of what a layout will look like. Android phones come in a wide variety of sizes and the reason you needed to wrap your layout in a `ScrollView` is that your view content's height is larger than the height of the physical device. Now that's not necessarily a bad thing, but maybe you just don't want a `ScrollView`. To fix this, You could use something like `ConstraintLayout` and then setting up the correct constraints would allow you to resize the content to fit everything on any device's screen.

Google puts out a lot of great resources, here's a short training doc they have for `ConstraintLayout`: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/

Comment: Thank you so much.Not pretty familiar with ConstraintLayout right now,but I did not know that the preview is just an estimation.